# Meteor Iron-Router Users subscription not subscribing fast enough? Loads subscription data of previous route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got this in my router:

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'

Router.map () ->
  @route 'home',
    path: '/'
    waitOn: ->
      Meteor.subscribe('users')
      Meteor.subscribe('instruments')
      Meteor.subscribe('instrumentList')
    data: ->
      Meteor.users.find().fetch()

  @route 'edit_form',
    path: 'edit_profile'
    waitOn: ->
      Meteor.subscribe('user', Meteor.userId)
      Meteor.subscribe('users')
      Meteor.subscribe('instruments')
      Meteor.subscribe('instrumentList')
    data: ->
      Meteor.user()

Router.onBeforeAction("loading")
```

`home` is a GoogleMap displaying dropped pins from all the users in the system.

`home` needs to be subscribed to the entire `users` collection.

`edit_form` is a form for the currently logged -in user.

`edit_form` needs to be subscribed to only the`current_user` document.

1. When I first go to `home`, the map shows all of the pins from every user.
2. I then navigate to `edit_form` and it shows all the info for the current user.
3. I then navigate straight back to the map and it shows only the pin for the current user.

What's going on here? Why is the `home` route in step 3 now only displaying the pins for the current user even though I specifically told it to `waitOn` the subscription to the entire `users` collection AND use the data from `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`, which should fetch every user in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the way you have written `waitOn` it will only wait on the last thing (coffeescript returns the last thing from the function). so in your case its only going to wait for `Meteor.subscribe('instrumentList')`

return all the subscriptions in an array.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Gah..... I had this same exact problem before on another project and I applied the same solution that you just described. And I forgot to do it for this current project. Actually, I forgot how javascript worked... you can only return one value in a JS function because return only runs once - if you want to return multiple things you have to wrap those things into an object or array.